# Typescript Best practice for enum to object type

Tags: typescript

Suppose we have an enum like this,

```
enum CustomerType {
   New = 'new',
   Owner = 'self',
   Loyal = 'subscriber'
}
```

using this makes it easier to add checks like

```
if(customer.type === CustomerType.New)
```

Whats the best practise, for typing an object with the enum values as keys,
In this case, lets say we have a method called `getCustomerType` that would return

```
{ 
   new: true,
   self: false,
   subscriber: false
}
```

Also please note simplifying this to return only true key might not be possible due to design :)

What I have tried so far is something like

```
type CustomerConfig = { [key in CustomerType]: boolean }
```

Now lets say I want to get the first key from this object which is true,I would do something like this.

```
export const getCustomer = (obj: CustomerConfig): CustomerType => {
    const customerType = Object.keys(obj).find(x => {
        // Object.keys return `string[]` instead of keyof type https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20853
        return obj[x as keyof CustomerConfig]
    })
    return customerType as CustomerType
}

const tempCustomer = getCustomer({
    'new': true,
    'self': false,
    'subscriber': false
})

console.log(tempCustomer === CustomerType.New)  // true
console.log(tempCustomer === CustomerType.Owner) //false
```

Is there a better way of doing this.?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest, that you can do some improvements:

- find function of array can return undefined in case it won't find any matches, so it's better to add this type too and make some additional checks
- as you say, typescript return wrong type for Object.keys, so you can just say typescript the right type inplace

```
export const getCustomer = (obj: CustomerConfig): CustomerType | undefined => {
  return (Object.keys(obj) as Array<keyof CustomerConfig>)
     .find(x => obj[x])
}

const tempCustomer = getCustomer({
    'new': true,
    'self': false,
    'subscriber': false
})
```